Error: peg$SyntaxError: Expected Character but "&" Found While Parsing SVG Path Data in JavaScript
I am working with an SVG file and converting it to JSON using svgson library. Additionally, I am using the svg-path-to-polygons library to decode the d attribute in the path element. However, I am encountering the following error:
peg$SyntaxError: Expected ",", ".", [ \t\n\r], [+\-], [0-9], [Aa], [Cc], [Hh], [Ll], [Mm], [Qq], [Ss], [Tt], [Vv], [Zz], [eE], or end of input but "&" found.

Here is a snippet of the SVG JSON data I am working with:
{
    "name": "g",
    "type": "element",
    "value": "",
    "attributes": {
        "id": "nopointer-base"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "element",
            "value": "",
            "attributes": {
                "fill": "#F2F2F2",
                "d": "M1737.5,678.8h-811c-11,0-20,9-20,20V1138h-137v291.5h184.1v245H1117v265.1h232.9l68.6-65.9l0.1-780.4&#xA;\t\t\th75.9V932.5h232.4l30.6-31.8V698.8C1757.5,687.7,1748.5,678.8,1737.5,678.8z"
            },
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}

Environment:

Libraries: svgson, svg-path-to-polygons

Steps to Reproduce:

Parse the SVG file to JSON using svgson.
Attempt to decode the d attribute using svg-path-to-polygons.

Expected Behavior:
The d attribute should be decoded without syntax errors.
Actual Behavior:
The following error is thrown: peg$SyntaxError: Expected ",", ".", [ \t\n\r], [+\-], [0-9], [Aa], [Cc], [Hh], [Ll], [Mm], [Qq], [Ss], [Tt], [Vv], [Zz], [eE], or end of input but "&" found.
Question:
How can I resolve this syntax error? Is there an issue with the format of the d attribute string, or is there something I am missing in the usage of the svgson or svg-path-to-polygons libraries?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Looks like it is not liking the &#xA; - which appears to be the HTML hexadecimal numeric character reference for a line break. Try and replace it with \n, or remove it completely.

You should probably check if svgjson has any sanitizing options or ask the developers to add it as a feature via a issue report. Otherwise remove all newlines and tabs beforehand via regex.

Resolved the error using "he" lib. used for decoding the json data and the issue was resolved.
